# How to find the max absolute value for each level of a multi-index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to find the max absolute value for each level of a multi-index data frame?

Here's how the data looks like:

```
                        data
            a   b   c   
            1   X   1   -2
                X   2   +2
            2   X   1   -1
                X   2   +2
                Y   1   +6
            3   X   1   -5
                Y   1   -3
                Y   2   +5
```

Here's what I expect to receive while keeping level 1 and 2 of the multi-index:

```
                        data
                a   b   
                1   X   2
                2   X   2
                    Y   6   
                3   X   -5
                    Y   +5
```

Comment: `df.abs().max(level=[0, 1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `idxmax`:

```
idx = df['data'].abs().groupby(level=[0,1]).idxmax()
df.loc[idx]
```

Result:

```
       data
a b c      
1 X 1    -2
2 X 2     2
  Y 1     6
3 X 1    -5
  Y 2     5
```

Explantion:

```
idx = df['data'].abs()          # convert the `data` column to its absolute value
        .groupby(level=[0,1])   # group by the first two levels (`a` and `b`)
        .idxmax()               # find the index of the row with max value in each group
df.loc[idx]                     # get the rows at indexes `idx`
```

Comment: Great solution! What's the explanation behind? Could you please share any reference to read and understand it better?